# Incorrect syntax near the keyword "AS"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, syntax-error

I'm getting an "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'" error, but i can't seem to find whats incorrect?

```
UPDATE tblMedlem AS M 
INNER JOIN tblNavn AS N ON M.fldNavnID = N.fldID 
SET N.fldNavn=@Navn
,   M.fldAdresse=@Adr
,   M.fldPostNr=@Post
,   M.fldBy=@By
,   M.fldTlf=@Tlf
,   M.fldEmail=@Mail
,   M.fldStrID=@StrID
,   M.fldStatusID=@StatusID 
WHERE M.fldID = @ID
```

Comment: Your update can only affect a single table at any time. Your `SET` section seems to try to affect both N and M. Can you explain which table you're trying to update here?

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps what you meant was:

```
UPDATE M
SET 
-- N.fldNavn = @Navn -- not legal!
   M.fldAdresse = @Adr,
   M.fldPostNr = @Post,
   M.fldBy = @By,
   M.fldTlf = @Tlf,
   M.fldEmail = @Mail,
   M.fldStrID = @StrID,
   M.fldStatusID = @StatusID 
FROM dbo.tblMedlem AS M 
INNER JOIN dbo.tblNavn AS N 
ON M.fldNavnID = N.fldID 
WHERE M.fldID = @ID;
```

But as I suggested in my comment, you can't update both `tblMedlem` and `tblNavn` with a single `UPDATE`.

Comment: I need to update both fldNavn from tblNavn, (which is represented in tblMedlem with an ID in fldNavnID) and i also need to update all the M fields.

Comment: Then you need to write two `UPDATE` statements. Again, *an UPDATE statement can only affect one table* (unless you write a trigger to handle updating the second table). Which would still be two `UPDATE` statements.